# jQuery update table row depending on how user inputs data

Tags: jquery

I have a table with rows of 2 input text boxes in each row:

```
<table>
    <tr><td><input id="1_1" type="text"></td><td><input id="1_2" type="text"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input id="2_1" type="text"></td><td><input id="2_2" type="text"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input id="3_1" type="text"></td><td><input id="3_2" type="text"></td></tr>
</table>
```

If the user has just one of the input texts filled in, I would like to append a certain icon in front of the row.  If the user has both inputs filled in, I would like to append a different type of icon.  All of this occurs on a per row basis.  How would I go about accomplishing this?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried anything? Seems like some pretty straightforward jQuery to me.

[Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/ebiewener/Zs5sb/1/) where I've added an additional `<td>` prior to the input fields and inserted a `<div class="icon"></div>` inside of it as a placeholder for the icon you want.

The jQuery for changing it is the following:

```
$(function(){
    $('input').keyup(function(){
        var row = $(this).parent().parent();
        var inputsChanged = 0;
        row.find('input').each(function(){
            if($(this).val() !== '') inputsChanged++;
        });
        if(inputsChanged === 1){
            row.find('.icon').css('background-color','red');
        }else if(inputsChanged === 2){
            row.find('.icon').css('background-color','green');
        }else if(inputsChanged === 0){
            row.find('.icon').css('background','none');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: No.  I didn't really know where to begin with the one because of the multiple elements that I needed to keep track of.  I had some code I did a couple of months ago but it was clunky and didn't really work.  This helps.  Thanks!

Comment: I have a question. I have this other feature that helps "paste" in data where I automatically set the values via .val().  This does not trigger the .keyup() function.  I tried using .change() but that did not work.  Do you have any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: For that, I'd put all the code inside the keyup event I wrote into a separate function. Then, just call that function inside the keyup event, as well as right after doing the paste. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ebiewener/Zs5sb/2/